# How to convert 1 dimensional object array into 2 dimension based on certain key in vue compoent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My modules vue like this :

```
[types.GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES] (state,{ stores }) {
    state.product_categories = {}
    console.log(stores);
    stores.forEach(message => {
        set(state.product_categories, message.id, message)
    })
    console.log('test')
    console.log(state.product_categories)
},
```

The result of `console.log(stores)` like this :

[image]

I want to change the object to be two dimensional object array by key parent_category_id

How can I do it?

**Update** :

For example :

parent_category_id = 1, 2, 3

parent_category_name = asia, europa, africa

id = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20

name = japan, korea, arab, england, spain, italy, south africa

I want to display like this :

```
asia
   japan
   korea
   arab
europa
   england
   spain
   italy
africa
   south africa
```

So I need to convert object one dimensional to be object two dimensional

Answer (score 0):

> I hope it will help you to achieve your solution

```js
var dataArr=[{
 id:1,
 name:'japan',
 parent_category_id:1,
 parent_category_name:'asia'
},{
 id:2,
 name:'england',
 parent_category_id:2,
 parent_category_name:'europa'
},{
 id:3,
 name:'korea',
 parent_category_id:1,
 parent_category_name:'asia'
},{
 id:4,
 name:'arab',
 parent_category_id:1,
 parent_category_name:'asia'
},{
 id:5,
 name:'south africa',
 parent_category_id:3,
 parent_category_name:'africa'
},{
 id:6,
 name:'spain',
 parent_category_id:2,
 parent_category_name:'europa'
},{
 id:7,
 name:'italy',
 parent_category_id:2,
 parent_category_name:'europa'
}],
output ={};
dataArr.map((item,index,arr)=>{
 if(!output[item.parent_category_name]){
  let result = arr.filter(val=>{
   return val.parent_category_id==item.parent_category_id;
  })
  output[item.parent_category_name] = result.map(val=>{
   return val.name;
  });
 }
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use for grouping:

```js
const groupBy = (arr, keyFn) => {
  const grouped = arr.reduce( (grouping, item) => {
    const key = keyFn(item);
    grouping[key] = grouping[key] || [];
    grouping[key].push(item);
    return grouping;
  }, {} );
  return Object.keys(grouped)
    .map(key => { return {key: key, group: grouped[key]}; });
}
```

You might call it like so:

```js
const itemByCategoryName = (items) => {
  const keyFn = item => item.parent_category_name
  return groupBy(items, keyFn)
    .map(group => { return { parent_category_name: group.key, grouped_items: group.group }; });
}
```

The output is an array of objects with key and nested array of items.